# how to make webview not full size on screen

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I would like to get my webview on iphone app, but it is making it full screen every time i add it. i added a webviewkit to most of the screen but the code seems to be over-riding this, i am not that good with code but just wondering can i change one thing on the code below to make it not full size

I added a webviewkit to some of the page but the code is overriding this somehow

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string:"https://weatheralertsireland.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
}
```

can you please see what mistake I am making to make it fit in the webviewKit on the screen

Answer (score 3):

you have to provide frame to webview to get it sized according to your requirment and from your code just remove loadView method.

```
let webView = WKWebView()
        let myURL = URL(string:"https://weatheralertsireland.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height/2, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height/2)
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
        webView.load(myRequest)
```

Comment: so completely remove the loadview method? when i did this i got many error, sorry a complete newbie

Comment: Just copy and paste this code in viewdidload. hope it would help. If it does please up vote the answere.

Comment: sorry i am a bit lost, if you would not mind could you possibly rewrite the whole code if possible, thank you for spending the time with this.

Comment: you just need to paste this code in your controller's viewdidload and your webview will appear in center of the screen.

Comment: i only get a full white blank screen

Comment: override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }